# Should I save data to DB asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm using node express and postgress.
I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is a good practice or a very big mistake.
Save data to database asynchronously after I already return a result to the client.

I tried to demonstrate it with console.log to check if my server will be blocked during the saving.

Here you can see `status` route and `statusB` route.

```
  app.get("/statusB", async (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send("testAAA");
  });

  app.get("/status", async (req, res) => {
    const userStats = await UserController.getData("id")
    const x = test();

    return res.status(200).send(userStats);
  });

  async function test() {
    return new Promise(() => { 
      for (let x = 0; x < 10000; x++) {

        setTimeout( () => {
          console.log(x)
        }, 5000);
      }
    })
  }
```

What should I want to happen is if I send `/status` and right after send `statusB`.

I expect the output to be:

`/status` will return userStats data

`/StatusB` return 'testAAA'

and the counter will run asynchronously.

But actual the output is:

- `/status` return userStats data

- The counter run

- `/StatusB` return 'testAAA' **only after the counter finished**

The console log is only test to know if I can fetching and saving data to the database asynchronously instead of the console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your business case.

If it's alright for your customer to get a `200 OK` status code even if the saving might actually have failed, then sure, you can do it asynchronously after you've responded.

In other cases, you'll want to do the saving within the request and only respond after you're sure everything is safe and sound.

Comment: How should I do it?
As you can see in my question the event loop is blocked in the console.log.
```/statusB``` doesn't execute until the for loop finished

Comment: `console.log()` is synchronous, as is the for loop. Your database would not be.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on your logic if you want for example to return the saved resource to the client you should wait (`async/await` or `callback`) until the data is saved to the database but for example, if you want just log an action without any returns to the frontend you can save it asynchronously

Comment: How should I do it?
As you can see in my question the event loop is blocked in the console.log.
```/statusB``` doesn't execute until the for loop finished

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should save data to db asynchronously, because of the way nodejs works. If you wait for an answer from db (synchronously), nodejs block event loop and doesn't handle new requests from clients. BUT if your business logic rely on the fact that you should return the answer from db to client, you should do it synchronously and maybe think about workarounds or choose another runtime, if that will become a problem.

Comment: How should I do it?
As you can see in my question the event loop is blocked in the console.log.
```/statusB``` doesn't execute until the for loop finished